Types of destructured params in loops in typescript
I have an array that holds object with constant properties. I wish to use those properties to access data from another objects, like so:
const someObject = {
  mean: { a: 100, b: 200 },
  median: { c: 300, d: 400 },
} as const;

const someArray = [
  { type: 'mean', units: 'a' },
  { type: 'mean', units: 'b' },
  { type: 'median', units: 'd' },
] as const;

type ArrayItem = (typeof someArray)[number];

function accessItem({ type, units }: ArrayItem) {
  const group = someObject[type];
  const value = group[units];
  return value;
}

const resultArray = someArray.map(accessItem);

Now, ArrayItem is a union of three types. Unfortunately, on the destructuring, typescript doesn't understand that there are only certain allowed value pairs of type/units, and so units becomes a type 'a' | 'b' | 'd'. Now, what would be an idiomatic way of telling TypeScript that if type === 'mean' then units is of type 'a'| 'b' and it should be safe to use it for indexing the group object?
Playground link: https://tsplay.dev/WoeVjN

This can be solved using generics I think but the callback inside .map will not be as simple. You will have to pass in the correct generic parameter to inform accessItem what the type of type and units will be

You're running into ms/TS#30581; TS cannot directly see correlations across multiple uses of a value of a union type. Assuming you don't want to just give up and use type assertions, you can use the generics refactoring as described in ms/TS#47109, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thank you, after adapting it to the real-life example I can say that it's exactly what I needed.

If you have a value of a union type and refer to it twice in the same expression, TypeScript cannot keep track of the correlation between those references. This is described in detail in microsoft/TypeScript#30581.
In
function accessItem({ type, units }: ArrayItem) {
  const group = someObject[type];
  const value = group[units];
  return value;
}

you know the input is either of type { type: "mean"; units: "a" | "b" } or of type { type: "median"; units: "d" }, so that type and units are correlated in just the right way so that the code you wrote is valid. But all TypeScript can see in that single code block is that type is "mean" | "median" and that units is "a" | "b" | "d" and it's worried that, for example, type will be "mean" while units is "d".
If you want TypeScript to follow your logic with union types, you need to write multiple redundant code blocks to narrow the discriminated union:
function accessItem({ type, units }: ArrayItem): number {
  if (type === "mean") {
    const group = someObject[type];
    const value = group[units];
    return value;
  } else {
    const group = someObject[type];
    const value = group[units];
    return value;
  }
}

That's redundant but it works.

If, on the other hand, you want the compiler to see that your single code block behaves as you intend, then you need to switch away from unions and toward generics, in a particular way as laid out in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. The idea is to refactor your code so that all operations are written in terms of: a "base" key-value mapping type; mapped types over that base type, and generic indexes into those types.
For your example code, the base mapping type looks like this:
type ArrMapping = {
  [T in (typeof someArray)[number] as T["type"]]: T["units"]
}
/* type ArrMapping = {
    mean: "a" | "b";
    median: "d";
} */

We're going to write all the operations in terms of that.  Let's make ArrayItem generic, so that ArrayItem<"mean"> and ArrayItem<"median"> are the corresponding members of the ArrayItem union, and so that ArrayItem<"mean" | "median"> is the full union. Like this:
type ArrayItem<K extends keyof ArrMapping = keyof ArrMapping> =
  { [P in K]: { type: P, units: ArrMapping[P] } }[K]

That's a distributive object type as described in ms/TS#47109. I also made it take keyof ArrMapping as a default type parameter so that if you just write ArrayItem then it's the same union as before.
And now we can write accessItem like this:
function accessItem<K extends keyof ArrMapping>({ type, units }: ArrayItem<K>) {
  const so: { [P in keyof ArrMapping]: Record<ArrMapping[P], number> } = someObject;
  const group = so[type];
  const value: number = group[units];
  return value;
}

Note that I had to change the representation of the type of someObject from the original inferred type to a mapped type over ArrMapping. The new variable so has the same value as someObject. But now TypeScript will "understand" that so[type] is of type Record<ArrMapping[K], number> and so you can index into it with units, which is of type ArrMapping[K].  And that gives a number value.
And since every member of someArray is assignable to ArrayItem, and since accessItem returns number, you can map() someArray with accessItem to get a number[]:
const resultArray = someArray.map(accessItem);


Playground link to code
